# Cannot call tool execution using python -m

Tags: python, path, pip, aws-cloudformation

I am doing following on Jenkins:

```
python3 -m pip install cfn-lint
> Requirement already satisfied...
python3 -m cfn-lint
> /usr/bin/python3: No module named cfn-lint
```

What is wrong? Why cannot I use just installed tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package installs itself as [`cfnlint`](https://github.com/awslabs/cfn-python-lint/blob/ee7e2fc8d64c1bf4c2e939482eac605fd2f7e1f6/setup.py#L47) (not `cfn-lint`). That means you can run it via `python -m cfnlint`. It also exposes an entry point via [`cfn-lint`](https://github.com/awslabs/cfn-python-lint/blob/ee7e2fc8d64c1bf4c2e939482eac605fd2f7e1f6/setup.py#L87). That means you can do either of

```
$ python -m cfnlint
$ cfn-lint
```